# Перевести минуты в секунды и изменить значение в БД

Tags: c#, wpf

В базе данных длительность услуги хранится в секундах. В ListView отображаю их в минутах при помощи этого свойства:

C#:

```
public int Time
 { get
   {
     return (this.DurationInSeconds / 60);
   }
 }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Time,StringFormat={}{0:N0} МИНУТ}" 
Grid.Row="3" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="durTbox"/>
```

Теперь, на другой страницы я беру экземпляр ListView и изменяю его [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал дописать set к свойству, при вводе значения в поле - оно сразу изменяется на то, которое в БД.

```
public int Time
        { get
            {
                return (this.DurationInSeconds / 60);
            }

            set
            {
                value = value * 60;
            }
        }
```

Ничего не поменялось. Значение в текстбоксе меняется сразу на то, которое хранится в БД.
Необходимо перевести минуты в секунды и это значение изменить в БД.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь структурой `TimeSpan`

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед, используйте подходящие типы для этого всего. За время отвечает `TimeSpan` или `TimeOnly`. То есть, все ваши вычисления можно переделать в `public TimeSpan Time { get => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DurationInSeconds); set => value.TotalSeconds; }`. Касательно самой проблемы - свойства не обновляются магическим образом, чтоб UI их заного прочитал, надо реализоывать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и вызывать соответсвующее событие. То есть, вы сами в коде должны сказать "Ей, свойство "А" обновилос!".